# How to get the intent extras if the activity is `singleTask`?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an activity, which is a singleTask:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        System.out.printf("### MyAcitvity.onCreate: " + getIntent().getExtras());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        System.out.println("### MyActivity.onResume: " + getIntent().getExtras());
    }

    public void toNext(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, AaaActivity.class));
    }
}
```

and:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" />
```

No it has been started, and it started another activity called `AaaActivity`.

```
public class AaaActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.aaa);
    }

    public void jumpToFirst(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("aaa","bbb");
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

In the later one, there is a button which will trigger the `jumpToFirst` method to start the first one, and pass a data pair `aaa=bbb`. Since `MyActivity` is `singleTask`, it won't create a new one, instead, it will just back to the existing `MyActivity` instance.

My question is: how to get the passing extra data from `AaaActivity` in `MyActivity`?

You can see I have logged `onCreate` and `onResume` methods, but it prints null extra data.

```
11-16 08:44:17.833: INFO/System.out(5171): ### MyAcitvity.onCreate: null
11-16 08:44:19.417: INFO/System.out(5171): ### MyActivity.onResume: null
11-16 08:44:26.041: INFO/System.out(5171): ### MyActivity.onResume: null
11-16 08:44:28.897: INFO/System.out(5171): ### MyActivity.onResume: null
```

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Try setting the *launchMode* type of your `MyActivity` as **singleTop** and then override the following method to look for the new intent:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
    //now getIntent() should always return the last received intent
}
```

Comment: This solution also worked for me using a launchMode of singleTask.

Comment: with singleTask the extra that i'm passing is received with different values.

Comment: This really saved my day! My problem was: i opened other app through button in my app and then i really had problems to receive the intent content from this sharing app - there was just no reaction at all. Thx for this solution.

Comment: it works with launchMode of singleInstance also. Thanks.

Comment: Big thanks, and when start activity using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP ` , activity's launching path is  `onNewIntent --> onStart --> onResume`

Comment: it also worked with android:launchMode="singleInstance"

Answer (score 1):

If you must have single Task then use these flags for your intent:

```
 resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

if you use PendingIntent so also: PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT :

```
pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT );
```

(also use `onNewIntent` in your activity to handle the extras.)